# How to get all dll's from project via c#

Tags: c#, dll, reference, project

I want to know how to get all dll's names wich used in project.
For example, when we on Reference on Solution Explorer - we can see what dll are use.

But how to do this from code?

Thank you.

P.S. i cannot use it on runtime- i should parse all projects and find references dll.

P.P.S. For example, i run programm ,and then it parse all Folders and find *.csproj file of each project.So, programm should find all dll's that they use.

Comment: see solution 5 on this : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/88183/How-to-get-all-dll-name-which-is-reference-in-C-pr

Comment: Use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();` to get the referenced assemblies at runtime.

Comment: You ask how to do this from code, but not at runtime, what did you mean?

Comment: I mean,that my code should runs at another project and parse some other projects to find dll's from it.

Comment: Then you should probably parse the csproj xml file and get them from here